# Long to wide w/ two repeated measures

Tags: r

I know this has been asked numerous times on here under the rubric of "long to wide" but I've run into a situation where I have two value variables that are repeated measures.

```
          id sex  time      score1    score2
1  subject 1   m Time1 -0.20926263 0.2499310
2  subject 2   m Time1  0.17147511 3.2708905
3  subject 3   m Time1 -0.82619584 0.5993917
4  subject 4   f Time1 -0.95568823 4.4729726
5  subject 5   f Time1 -2.29939525 8.0101254
6  subject 1   m Time2 -0.37914702 3.6387589
7  subject 2   m Time2  0.26759909 4.9027533
8  subject 3   m Time2  0.07727621 2.1848642
9  subject 4   f Time2 -0.08613439 5.8747074
10 subject 5   f Time2 -0.02743044 4.3963938
11 subject 1   m Time3  0.07176053 3.7959496
12 subject 2   m Time3  0.46463917 5.2494579
13 subject 3   m Time3 -0.68764512 2.2639503
14 subject 4   f Time3 -0.56670061 2.3361909
15 subject 5   f Time3  1.70731774 5.8345116
```

Quick way to reproduce the data frame (DF).

```
DF<-data.frame(id=rep(paste("subject", 1:5, sep=" "), 3),              
               sex=rep(c("m","m","m","f","f"), 3),                     
               time=c(rep("Time1",5), rep("Time2",5), rep("Time3",5)), 
               score1=rnorm(15), score2=abs(rnorm(15)*4))
```

I can solve the issue of long to wide for two measured repeated measure variables using the `reshape` function from base but I was hoping for a `plyr` or `reshape2/1` answer, as these packages are generally much more intuitive to me.  If you have any other solutions go ahead and provide them as the learning would be great.

Solution from base:

```
wide <- reshape(DF, v.names=c("score1", "score2"), idvar="id",         
                timevar="time", direction="wide")                      
wide
```

Comment: ? I don't see what the close ("off topic") vote was for ... ?

Comment: Ben nailed it with reshape and with such little code.  I'm very open to other methods (not sure if/how to do this with data.table etc.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
library(reshape)
m <- melt(DF)
```

Simplest, but time and score are in the opposite order from your example (in case it matters)

```
cast(m,id+sex~...)
```

Or more explicitly:

```
cast(m,id+sex~variable+time)
```

You can cut this down to a one-liner:

```
recast(DF,id+sex~...)
```

If you like you can use the newer `reshape2` package instead of `reshape`, replacing `cast` with `dcast` (the version of `recast` included in `reshape2` doesn't give the desired result.)

Answer (score 2):

Ben's answer is great considering the date this question was asked. However, it should be noted that the `dcast` function included in more recent versions of "data.table" can handle problems like this without having to first `melt` the data. As such, it would be a more efficient approach to use.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(as.data.table(DF), id + sex ~ time, value.var = c("score1", "score2"))
##           id sex score1_Time1 score1_Time2 score1_Time3 score2_Time1 score2_Time2 score2_Time3
## 1: subject 1   m   0.78213630   -0.1557955  -0.10278773    1.5771598     1.013447    1.4583278
## 2: subject 2   m   0.07456498   -1.4707524   0.38767161    0.2372536     2.787854    3.0741317
## 3: subject 3   m  -1.98935170   -0.4781501  -0.05380504    4.4001015     2.226653    0.4493848
## 4: subject 4   f   0.61982575    0.4179416  -1.37705956    3.0527030     2.755023    3.5244309
## 5: subject 5   f  -0.05612874    1.3586796  -0.41499456    0.6580944     2.829981    1.5924235
```