# Convert R dataframe from long to wide format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
 df <- data.frame(left=letters[1:4], right=replicate(1,sample(0:100,12,rep=TRUE)))
```

I looks like this (numbers might be different because on the random function)

```
   left  right
1     a     6
2     b    97
3     c    78
4     d    28
5     a    61
6     b    58
7     c    56
8     d    28
9     a    90
10    b    83
11    c    72
12    d    17
```

The first column is headers for a table, repeating 3 times. The new dataframe should look like this:

```
a  b  c  d
6  97 78 28
61 58 56 28
90 83 72 17
```

When I use

```
spread(df,left, right)
```

it looks like this:

```
    a  b  c  d
1   6 NA NA NA
2  NA 97 NA NA
3  NA NA 78 NA
4  NA NA NA 28
5  61 NA NA NA
6  NA 58 NA NA
7  NA NA 56 NA
8  NA NA NA 28
9  90 NA NA NA
10 NA 83 NA NA
11 NA NA 72 NA
12 NA NA NA 17
```

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps this would work:
`data.frame(a = df[which(df$left == 'a'),2],
                  b = df[which(df$left == 'b'),2],
                  c = df[which(df$left == 'c'),2],
                  d = df[which(df$left == 'd'), 2])`

Comment: I see we're not flagging duplicates anymore

Comment: @Alex couldn't find a good one soon enough; if you have a good one: vote to close as duplicate & I will marked it immediately as a duplicate

Comment: `df$group <- rep(1:3, each=4); xtabs(right~group+left, data=df)`

Comment: @Jaap Does this do the trick? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192136/long-to-wide-w-two-repeated-measures

Comment: @RichardErickson not good enough imo

Comment: `unstack(df, form = right ~ left)` is in the classic long to wide dupe. It is the last answer

Comment: @PierreLafortune you're correct; marked as duplicate now

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution is probably using the `rowid` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- dcast(setDT(df), rowid(left) ~ left, value.var = "right")
dt[, names(dt)[1] := NULL]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dt
>     a  b  c  d
> 1: 18 52 67 12
> 2: 36 74 61 86
> 3: 81 41 82  3
> ```

Comment: get error message when using rowID  > dcast(setDT(df), rowid(left) ~ left, value.var = "right")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rowid"

Comment: @user3482393 you have to install the [development version of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for access to the `rowid` function

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with dplyr and tidyr (appreciate it's not as neat as other answers!):

```
df %>% 
mutate(rowId = 1:n()) %>%
group_by(rowId) %>% 
spread(left, right) %>% #gives you wide df with NAs
ungroup() %>% 
select(-rowId) %>% 
mutate(temp = rep(1:3, each = 4)) %>% 
group_by(temp) %>% 
summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
select(-temp)
```

Comment: it's a little nicer like this: `df %>% group_by(left) %>% mutate(b = row_number()) %>% spread(left, right)`

Comment: both of these works great, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jeremycg, much neater.